# how to fix grub after Mate update

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, grub

I have a laptop, which originally had windows with EFI and I installed ubuntu Mate. Mate became slow in 2020 and I installed antix on the windows partition, so I had Mate alongside antix. Last week I did the update suggested in Mate and grub disappeared, it goes straight to Mate. I tried to install MX Linux over the antix, but get the same boot straight into Mate. How can I recover grub? I have:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 298.1 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Disk model: TOSHIBA MQ01ABF0
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 50A3A648-A93E-468F-9B76-29983D4C92BE

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    821247    819200   400M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2     821248   1435647    614400   300M EFI System
/dev/sda3    1435648   1697791    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4    1697792 377260031 375562240 179.1G Linux root (x86)
/dev/sda5  614039552 625141759  11102208   5.3G Linux swap
/dev/sda7  377260032 614039551 236779520 112.9G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

MX linux is on sda4 and Mate on sda7.

New info:
I think the problem may be related to my old Mate setup. I had hibernation in my grub with resume pointing to a uuid. that changed after I installed antix over windows and expanded the swap. I now updated my /etc/default/grub on the Mate partition to point to the correct uuid, but when I ran update-initramfs it still complains:

```
stephen@stephen-AO725:~$ sudo update-initramfs -u
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-74-generic
cryptsetup: ERROR: Couldn't resolve device 
    /dev/disk/by-uuid/30a0ce15-7a08-48a2-ac6b-ba73822c05c2
cryptsetup: ERROR: Couldn't resolve device 
    UUID=30a0ce15-7a08-48a2-ac6b-ba73822c05c2
W: initramfs-tools configuration sets RESUME=UUID=30a0ce15-7a08-48a2-ac6b-ba73822c05c2
W: but no matching swap device is available.
```

how can I fix this? why is cryptsetup getting involved in my boot?

Comment: tried grub repair and grup re-install from MX, no luck. ran boot-repair from Mate and this is the paste bin: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/SKZFb6G9Gq/ again no grub.

Comment: Did you switch to a BIOS boot. You have UEFI system, with UEFI boots of all systems. But also have a BIOS grub in MBR that may or may not work. You need to make sure you are booting in UEFI boot mode. You can also remove Windows folder in ESP, so os-prober does not keep adding it to grub menu. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198221/cloning-ssd-also-cloned-boot-options/1198228#1198228

Comment: I did not switch to BIOS. the problem occurred after the Mate update. fixing grub from antix live did not help, so I did the fresh install of MX over antix. then I ran grub re-install from MX and that could not install in ESP mode, so I did it in MBR mode. should I do sth in the BIOS setup?

Comment: Do not mix UEFI & BIOS/CSM/Legacy boot modes on same drive. You break things. If system is UEFI, you need to resolve UEFI install issues. If you reinstall, rerun Boot-Repair, from live installer when booted in UEFI boot mode.

Comment: I went in BIOS and it is setup as UEFI mode, security boot disabled. what will happen if I do a full disk install of a linux system? I am afraid not to brick the laptop. there is no problem about data. do I need to keep alive the original EFI partition or a new install will take care of EFI?

Comment: I prefer to partition in advance using gpt partitioning. But a new UEFI install will create an ESP, if one does not exist when installing to blank drive. But if drive is not first drive, ESP must be on first drive. UEFI boot setting in UEFI, is only for installed systems. You can boot USB flash drive in either UEFI or BIOS. Or if you used Rufus, you create an installer that only works in UEFI or only in BIOS mode. You always want UEFI.

Comment: I think the problem may be related to my old Mate setup. I had hibernation in my grub with resume pointing to a uuid. that changed after I installed antix over windows and expanded the swap. I now updated my /etc/default/grub on the Mate partition to point to the correct uuid, but when I ran update-initramfs it still complains:

Comment: I edited the top post, see under New info.

Comment: Your UUID 30a0,.... is shown in fstab as swap partition, but does not exist? Check fstab & UUIDs. If a new install creates new swap in place of old swap it changes UUID. Then old install needs its fstab updated with correct UUID.

Comment: I fixed the fstab and now mate can hibernate. upgraded Mate to 20.10 and still no grub. Final question: what is the chance the laptop bricks if I install a linux distro using the "entire disk" option? Bios does not allow a partition for loading to be chosen, only UEFI vs Legacy mode. It is now in UEFI mode, security boot is disables.

Comment: I typically suggest dual boot for those that were Windows users. We see many want to reinstall Windows after converting to Linux. It took me 5 years before I quit using last Windows app & I do not game. If system boots with Linux then full drive install will work. If only one install, or only one seen by os-prober, grub menu will not appear. I did change grub setting to show menu always. In grub settings: `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu` https://askubuntu.com/questions/1319810/ubuntu-20-04lts-grub-os-selection-menu-shows-up-on-restart-but-not-on-power-on

Comment: this is a legal win10, but hardware cannot support win any more. I will try with MX as a full disk and report results.

Comment: this is not an answer to my question, but a workaround to get a working laptop. I installed MX over the entire disk. it could not boot. then I did install grub. that took me to a grub prompt. then I did grub repair and it now boots and works fine with MX as the only os.